# Generic Answer when Fine Tuning OpenAI Model

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api, text-davinci-003

I have prepared a dataset and trained a **davinci** model using [FineTuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning). It gives out the correct answer for any variant of questions that exist in the dataset.

But how to fine tune the model to give out something like a "Sorry I do not know the answer to this question", if we ask anything not in the dataset? For example if I ask "Where was the 2020 Olympics hosted?", it should give out a generic "Do Not Know" answer, as this question does not exist in the dataset.